# What is the Random Control Logic in the 6502?

Tags: processor, 6502

I am currently developing a subset of the 6502 in LogiSim and at the current stage I am determining which parts to implement and what can be cut out. One of my main resources is [Hanson's Block Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxwKp.jpg).

I am currently trying to determine how exactly the instructions are decoded into the control lines. In the diagram below, there are two parts, the Decode ROM and the Random Control Logic.

[image: confusing part of the diagram]

How exactly does the 6502 decode the program instructions into control lines? As a follow up, Is it possible to simplify this area to eliminate the Random Control Logic and create the decoding with only one ROM?

Comment: You might consider asking this question at https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Somewhat related, this Computer Architecture article compares random logic with the alternative microcode for instruction decode. https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/80454/what-is-random-logic-why-is-it-needed/80622#80622 Full disclosure, it's my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm on the outskirts of my knowledge here, but my understanding is that the PLA decode ROM outputs its 130 control signals as a function of opcode and cycle, and the random logic is a purely functional unit that takes the PLA output as input in order to control the rest of the chip. I think you could combine the two into a single ROM; from looking at [the die shot](http://static.righto.com/images/ARM1/6502_labeled.png) the random logic is about twice as large as the PLA so my guess would be that time/cost considerations, possibly including intelligent task subdivision and almost certainly including a calculation of debugging time as the 6502 was laid out literally by hand, using pen and ruler, led to the combined approach.

Comment: Thanks so much, that really helps.